# Write xml file with elements depending on the type of action to be performed

Tags: xml, file-management

I need to express in xml a list of actions that my program can do. The problem is that some actions need of additional elements and others do not. For example if my program has to perform actions on files: if I delete the only thing that interests me is the path, if the program does the copy... again I need the path, but also a path of destination .. How to write an xml file so structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<actions>
  <action name="FileCopy">
    <params>
      <param name="SourcePath" value="c:\source.txt"/>
      <param name="DestPath" value="c:\dest.txt"/>
    </params>
  </action>
  <action name="FileDelete">
    <params>
      <param name="DeletePath" value="c:\source.txt"/>
    </params>
  </action>
  <action name="ReloadCache"/>
  <action name="Alert">
   <params>
     <param name="Message" value="Done!"/>
   </params>
  </action>
</actions>
```

You could of course remove the `params` level and put `param` tags directly under the `action` tag, however the proposed structure will allow to add other types of nodes under the `action` tag (for example, validation callbacks) without breaking too much things.

Comment: While the example above works as-is, it may not be entirely flexible at a later date. It's a highly debatable topic, but many recommend that attributes be limited to containing meta-data regarding the content of the element, rather than value data: e.g.: ´<weight units="kg">75</weight>´ See this post for more discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521454/how-should-you-structure-your-xml-file

Comment: @James: at least, that's how standard .NET `appSettings` conf sections are structured (`<add key="..." value="..."/>`).

Comment: true, though that doesn't necessarily count as a good endorsement :-) This isn't really a discussion for here anyway, just a general observation, so +1 for providing a working answer.