# Retrieving default values in XML tree hierarchy

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

Is it possible to set and retrieve default values in an XML hierarchy.

```xml
    <commission-rate>
        <region-NA> <!-- can we set a default at this level, if userId is NOT 123, it should return this default -->
            <userId-123>
                9
            </userId-123>
        </region-NA>
    </commission-rate>
```

For example, if I want to retrieve commission-rate.region-NA, it should return the default (say 5), but commission-rate.region-NA.userId-123 should pull 9 as the value.

Also, is using XML tags like this recommended or I should be using named attributes (e.g.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For your first question:*

XML document on its own does not contain any default values. It just contains the values that the document contains. Everything else is undefined.

*For your second question:*

Please see: [How should you structure your xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/521454/367456)

Comment: Got your point. What I mean is - Is it possible to set anything as default at the tag <region-NA>, or I need to include an element like <default>5</default>

Comment: That is all up to you, there is no "default" you can set inside the XML document. So it's likely that you will create your own element like <default>5</default> to carry your wished default value.